# Django HoneyPot Change Password Issue

Tags: python, passwords, login, django, honeypot

I would appreciate if you could give me any clue! As I don't have experience in this, probably I've misunderstood smth.

I'm using *honeypot*, more specifically `honeypot.middleware.HoneypotMiddleware` with `HONEYPOT_FIELD_NAME` in my API (*settings.py*).

As for the moment it's enough, I'm using the basic implementation for *login, password change, reset* from `django.contrib.auth`. In *login* I did a small customization so I added it in the url (`authentication_form=CustomAuthenticationForm`).

So I don't konw what I'm missing because the *login* page works (it is also a form), but the *password change, reset* ones are returning *400 Bad Request. Honey Pot Error (honey_pot_fieldname). Request aborted*.

django: 2.1.2
django-honeypot: 0.7.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**[Updating with solution]**

Finally I achieved it!
I only had to add at the top of the template *change_password_form.html* the line

```
{% load honeypot %}
```

and within the form including the tag:

```
{% render_honeypot_field "field_name" %}
```

For achieve this helped me this article
[django-honeypot](http://www.filehungry.com/product/linux_software/utilities/django-honeypot/)

Hope that will be helpful for others.